Rendering Child in Child
Im trying to solve, which should be a relatively straight forward issue. I am trying to render a component in the following page. I defined a layout for all children under dashboard. Im not sure if another layout needs to be defined to display within the child of dashboard. At the moment the component appears on the left side where Sidebar has previously been set

app/
├── context/
├── firebase/
├── mobile/
├── portal/
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── AddGroup.jsx ** THIS COMPONENT **
│   │   └── Sidebar.jsx
│   └── dashboard/
│       ├── groups/
│       │   └── page.jsx ** SHOW COMPONENT HERE **
│       ├── individuals/
│       ├── settings/
│       ├── statistics/
│       ├── layout.jsx
│       └── page.jsx
├── login/
├── utils/
├── dummydata.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
└── page.tsx

All help appreciated
Layout of dashboard/layout
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className="min-w-screen min-h-screen bg-gray-200 m-10 flex">
            <div className="w-1/4 p-4">
                <Sidebar/>
            </div>
            <div className='flex-1 flex flex-col'>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DashboardLayout;

Component: AddGroup
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogHeader, DialogBody, DialogFooter, Button, Input } from "@material-tailwind/react";

const AddGroup = ({ open, handleOpen }) => {
  return (
    <Dialog open={open} handler={handleOpen}>
      <DialogHeader>Create a Travel Group</DialogHeader>
      <DialogBody>
        <div className="">
          <Input type="text" label="Group Name" />
          <Input type="text" label="Destination" />
          <Input type="date" label="Date" />
          <Input type="number" label="Number of Participants" />
        </div>
      </DialogBody>
      <DialogFooter>
        <Button variant="text" color="red" onClick={handleOpen}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button variant="gradient" color="green" onClick={() => { /* Add logic to handle form submission */ }}>
          Create
        </Button>
      </DialogFooter>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default AddGroup;

Desired location to display aboev component
'use client'
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Button } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { PlusIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import AddGroup from '../../components/AddGroup'

const Groups = () => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);


  return (
    <div className='flex-1 text-gray-800 flex flex-col'>
      <AddGroup open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen} />
      <div className='flex-row flex items-center justify-between'>
        <div className='text-4xl font-medium ml-5 mt-10'>Groups</div>
        <div className='mr-10 mt-10'>
          <Button onClick={(handleOpen)} autoCapitalize='false' size="lg" color="white" className="flex items-center gap-3 font-normal normal-case">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="size-5">
            <path d="M10.75 4.75a.75.75 0 0 0-1.5 0v4.5h-4.5a.75.75 0 0 0 0 1.5h4.5v4.5a.75.75 0 0 0 1.5 0v-4.5h4.5a.75.75 0 0 0 0-1.5h-4.5v-4.5Z" />
          </svg>
            Add Group
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex-1 flex justify-center items-center text-gray-500'>
        No groups created
      </div>
      <AddGroup open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Groups;


what have you tried so far? did you import and then render the component?

ive now added the relevant parts of the code and a screenshot of the issue

Remove duplicates and ensure that styles and classes are correctly
const Groups = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);

    return (
        <div className="flex-1 text-gray-800 flex flex-col">
            <div className="flex-row flex items-center justify-between">
                <div className="text-4xl font-medium ml-5 mt-10">Groups</div>
                <div className="mr-10 mt-10">
                    <Button
                        onClick={handleOpen}
                        autoCapitalize="false"
                        size="lg"
                        color="white"
                        className="flex items-center gap-3 font-normal normal-case">
                        <PlusIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
                        Add Group
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex justify-center items-center text-gray-500">
                No groups created
            </div>
            <AddGroup open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Groups;


The problem is still the same as per the screenshot i have attached

Check layout in routing there might be a problem

Make sure that the parent element must have the css attribute position: relative and the child element that you want to float must have the position: absolute attribute.
<div className='flex-1 text-gray-800 flex flex-col' style="position: relative;"> // parent
      <AddGroup open={open} handleOpen={handleOpen} /> // child
      // other code


The same problem still occurs. Issue as you can see is that the dialog appears at the top left

Make sure the "add group" component doesn't get the position: fixed attribute because Fix doesn't care if its parent is limited
